# 'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer' - django rest frame work

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'
Request Method: PUT
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/masters/sku-image/create
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'Request' object has no attribute 'accepted_renderer'

I am getting above error when I hit saving image

API VIEW:

```
class CreateSKUImageAPI(LoggingMixin, generics.CreateAPIView):
    """ Create SKU Image"""
    queryset = master_models.SKUImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = master_serializers.SKUImageSerializer
```

Serializer:

```
class SKUImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(write_only=True)
    image_url = serializers.CharField(source="image.url", read_only=True)
    class Meta(object):
        model = master_models.SKUImage
        fields = ('sku', 'image', 'image_url', 'id')
```